# Microsoft Graph: Getting 400 Bad Request when trying to fetch mailboxSettings

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=3) and have implemented Microsoft login via OAuth and Azure. Also, I have fetched data from Microsoft Graph to store in my database.

Here is a code sample to fetch data using Microsoft Graph:

```
$graph  = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken->getToken());
$user   = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mobilePhone,jobTitle,userPrincipalName') 
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();
```

The code works fine and I get my desired data.

However, when I change the url from `'/me?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mobilePhone,jobTitle,userPrincipalName'` to `'/me?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mobilePhone,jobTitle,userPrincipalName,mailboxSettings'`, I am getting this error:-

```
 Error Code:- 400| Error Message:- Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mobilePhone,jobTitle,userPrincipalName,mailboxSettings` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": "AuthenticationError", "message": "Error authenticating with resource", "innerErr (truncated...) | Error Location:- Line No. 113 in file C:\xampp7.2\htdocs\kaec\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php
```

As you can see, I am getting the 400 Bad Request error only when I am adding `'mailboxSetttings'` in the query string of the url.

Why am I getting this error? The tutorial itself has used `'mailboxSetttings'` in their sample code?

PS: Two days ago, it worked absolutely fine when I used `'mailboxSetttings'` in the query. But today, I am getting 400 - Bad Request.

Comment: Could you please share what is the inner error is?

Comment: Are you using a personal MSA account?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma yes

Comment: Check if there is proper exchange license for your account. Also try your call in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) logging in with the same account.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `MailboxSettings.Read` and `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` permissions to be able to read, update, create, and delete your mailbox settings.

Comment: Yes. I have enabled them in the Web App

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user2250152 answer, at first I used an access token which doesn't with the scope of MailboxSettings.ReadWrite, and I called the api

`'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surName,mail,mobilePhone,jobTitle,userPrincipalName,mailboxSettings'`

it returns 403 error(not the same as yours 400), I checked the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and found that the 'mailboxSettings' property really exists but even I used beta version of the api I still can't find it in response. So I tried to add api permission when generate the access token, finally it worked for me.

I think you can debug your program to check if the access token you used to call the api has the scope of 'MailboxSettings.ReadWrite', just decode the token and you can see it in the claim "scp", because you said that your programs run absolutely fine before. So maybe you've added more other scopes(not belong to graph) when generate access token.

Comment: MailboxSettings.Read  has been added while generating the accesstoken. I however say a different issue. While using one email, I couldn't read mailboxSettings, when I used another email I could read mailboxSettings. Why is such difference?

Comment: Could you pls explain what it mean 'used another email'? You mean that you changed the contact email in your account profile or used another user id in the api?

Comment: Pls view the user's license in azure portal>azure ad>user>License, compare the differences of the two users' license. By the way, Office 365 E3 license contains Exchange online, and so on.